# Are the Swift language headers available online?

Tags: header-files, swift

Are the Swift headers available anywhere? I'd like to dig a bit deeper into some of the classes, but I don't have my Mac with me at the moment. Is there another option to view the Swift language source files?

Comment: Swift does not use header files, btw. Also I think if you just start a new swift project in xcode 6, you can see it in action. Swift just imports frameworks and maps them appropriately, i'm not sure that the entire things were rewritten with swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, in the Xcode6 beta, the swift "header files" aren't really header files. (i.e. they don't exist on disk in plain text format.) They appear to be getting generated on the fly by Xcode from the `*.swiftmodule` and `*.swiftdoc` files in the Xcode bundle.

Similarly, the swift declarations for Objective-C libraries appear to be being auto-generated on the fly. To the commenter: I've seen no indication that any of the pre-existing Apple-provided Objective-C libraries have been re-written in swift. Their header files are just being rewritten by Xcode on the fly as swift declarations.

Someone could trivially generate these files and copy and paste them and put them on the web somewhere, but I haven't seen it, and Apple doesn't appear to be publishing them in that way. (NB: This would almost certainly be a violation of their NDA.)

I'd say "keep an eye out"... it's probably only a matter of time.

Comment: it's been 3.5 years now and it seems that we have no decent doxygen replacement :-[