# How can I retrieve Swift "header" files for Cocoa APIs?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift

The way I know I can view the automatically-translated Swift versions of Cocoa APIs is by command-clicking a Cocoa type in Xcode. For example, here's what is generated for UITableViewController:

```
class UITableViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, NSObjectProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    init(style: UITableViewStyle)

    var tableView: UITableView!
    var clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear: Bool // defaults to YES. If YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
}
```

Is there an alternate way to make Xcode generate this Swift version? Preferably from the command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Swift REPL includes a helper `:print_decl <name> - print the AST representation of the named declarations`

This [blog post](http://ericasadun.com/2014/07/28/swift-docs-generation/) explains how you can write a simple script to help you use this to generate documentation for a specific type. I updated the script to allow using either OS X

```
#! /bin/sh
# usage: <shellscript> [--osx] typename

if [ "$1" = "--osx" ] ; then
    echo "import Cocoa\n:print_decl $2" | xcrun swift -deprecated-integrated-repl
else
    sdk_path=$(echo `xcrun --show-sdk-path` | sed 's#MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk#iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk#')
    echo "import UIKit\n:print_decl $1" | xcrun swift -deprecated-integrated-repl -sdk "$sdk_path"
fi
```

**Note 1:** The script defaults to using the iOS SDK. If you want to use the OS X SDK use the "--osx" option as the first parameter

**Note 2:** I prefer to leave out the file output that is part of the blog post so that I can use this script in other ways than just file generation

Comment: Interesting that the output seems distinctly different from what Xcode shows. Also, this can be used to see hidden definitions like `_Collection`.

Comment: There are comments on [Erica Sadun's blog post](https://www.instapaper.com/read/499591307) about how to get the command working under beta 6 and how to dump the UIKit versions as well.

Comment: Thanks @NateCook, I updated my answer with a version that will work with beta 6 and allows using OS X or iOS

Comment: Trying `xcrun swift -deprecated-integrated-repl -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk` -> `import Foundation` -> `:print_decl Foundation` crashes swift for me (log here: https://gist.github.com/JALsnipe/5fbad92d6c1dccff90f9). Does this work with Xcode 6.3?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the modern (non-"deprecated") REPL has a way of doing this too. Rather than `:print_module`, you can use `:type lookup`:

```
echo -e "import CoreGraphics\n:type lookup CoreGraphics" | swift
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038409/are-the-swift-language-headers-available-online), the "headers" are generated from the compiled Swift modules. These are located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/` where there are both `swiftdoc` and `swiftmodule` files, as well as the `dylib`s that contain the actual libraries.

There don't seem to be any tools to parse these at the time being. `class-dump` and `otool` are of no use. After some investigation, it seems Xcode communicates with SourceKitService (located at `...XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/sourcekitd.framework/XPCServices/SourceKitService.xpc`
) via XPC in order to get these headers — the best approach would probably be to try and duplicate those messages for yourself. Creating a DTrace instrument in Instruments, you can see a little bit of what's going on (this is when I <kbd>⌘</kbd>-clicked on CIFilter):

[image: dtrace]

And with `otool` we can see that SourceKitService has symbols such as `SwiftInterfaceGenContext` and `swift::ide::SyntaxModelWalker` which are probably related to all this. But it would take a lot of work to suss out exactly what messages are being passed and how you could get the headers yourself. Probably not worth it!

**Edit:** drewag's answer above shows that `swift -integrated-repl`'s `:print_decl` command can produce the headers.

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 12.5 the accepted answer no longer works as the `-deprecated-integrated-repl` flag is no longer supported. Going off of [@jtbandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887454/how-can-i-retrieve-swift-header-files-for-cocoa-apis#answer-39218030), the following works for me with Xcode 12.5:

```
// iOS
echo "import UIKit\n:type lookup UIKit" | swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios14.5

// macOS
echo "import AppKit\n:type lookup AppKit" | swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -target x86_64-apple-macosx11.3

// tvOS
echo "import UIKit\n:type lookup UIKit" | swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS14.5.sdk -target arm64-apple-tvos14.5

// watchOS
echo "import WatchKit\n:type lookup WatchKit" | swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS7.4.sdk -target arm64_32-apple-watchos7.4 

// macCatalyst
echo "import UIKit\n:type lookup UIKit" | swift -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios14.5-macabi -Fsystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Of course this is going to look slightly different for whichever SDKs you have installed on your machine, but everything else in the commands are the same.