# Generate Swift Interface from Objective-C Header from Command Line

Tags: swift, interop

In Xcode, for any Objective-C header, we can view the [Generated Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1914/_index.html), which shows how it is seen by Swift in interop.

I'd like to generate that from the **command line**. Any idea how to do it?

Bonus task: The header should be precompiled first, so all `#import`s should be replaced already.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/IDE/print_clang_header.swift

Comment: or this? https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten

Comment: or this? `export SOURCEKIT_LOGGING=1 && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

Comment: or this? http://ericasadun.com/2014/07/28/swift-docs-generation/

Comment: tried something out with SourceKitten, but no luck so far https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten/issues/221

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24887454/1529675

Answer (score 6):

Invoke interpreter command `:type lookup` on the module you are trying to inspect.

Suppose you have a header file named `header.h`. Put it into a separate directory, so that the interpreter would recognise it as a module. Also create a modulemap in the same directory. Let's call this directory `Mod`:

```
./
./Mod/
     /header.h
     /module.modulemap
```

Fill in the modulemap with the following:

```
module Mod {
  header "./header.h"
  export *
}
```

Once it's done, issue a command like this:

```
echo "import Mod\n:type lookup Mod" | swift -I./Mod | tail -n+2 >| generated-interface.swift
```

Alternatively, you might want use a command like this with equal effect:

```
echo "import Mod\n:print_module Mod" | swift -deprecated-integrated-repl -I./Mod >| generated-interface.swift
```

It's broken down as follows:

- first we echo the script to be executed: import module and type-lookup it;
- then we launch the interpreter and feed the script into it; the `-I` argument helps it find our module, which is crucial;
- then we cut off the “Welcome to Swift” part with Tail
- and write the result into `generated-interface.swift`.

While running the above commands, make sure your working directory is set to one level higher than the `Mod` directory.

Note that the output might not be exactly the same as from Xcode, but it's very similar.

---

Just for the record, if you want to produce the interface from a Swift file, then it's just this:

```
swiftc -print-ast file.swift
```

Comment: which swift version do you use? i use the lates stable 3.1, and get the error `invalid character in source file` for the `\n` in both command lines

Comment: Just checked with 3.1 and 4-beta — both worked well. Make sure `\n` gets expanded into a newline; might be an issue between single/double quotes in your shell.